# Kotlin JUnit test with mulitple expected exceptions

Tags: kotlin, exception, junit

What is the correct syntax for specifying mulitple exceptions in a JUnit test written in Kotlin?

I've tried the following but they do not compile:

```
@Test(expected = { MalformedURLException::class, RuntimeException::class })
fun shouldThrowMalformedUrlException() {
    ...
}

@Test(expected = MalformedURLException::class, RuntimeException::class)
fun shouldThrowMalformedUrlException() {
    ...
}

@Test(expected = [ MalformedURLException::class, RuntimeException::class ])
fun shouldThrowMalformedUrlException() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: is this a code review blocker?

Comment: I've moved away from specifying exceptions in the `@Test` annotation, as it's not flexible enough; in addition to issues with multiple types, it doesn't let you specify _which_ line should throw the exception.  I find it clearer and safer to use more fine-grained checks using something like [`assertFailsWith()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/kotlin.test/kotlin.test/assert-fails-with.html) instead.